# Reading Lua variables from JavaScript using lua.vm.js

Tags: javascript, lua

Im using the [lua.vm.js javascript library](https://github.com/kripken/lua.vm.js) in order to get some Lua code to execute in JavaScript.

The code works fine(its a very simple Lua example) but I cant get any variables declared in Lua into my JavaScript context.

The [REPL](http://kripken.github.io/lua.vm.js/repl.html) from the project allows me to test the following Lua code:

```
local key = { k1 = value}
local data = {
[key] = "something",
a = { b = 3 },
}
local v1 = data [key]
local v2 = data.a.b
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

In the output window, I can see that v1 and v2 are being printed and with the correct value, but I cant find a way to assign the value from data, for example, into a JS variable.

A little more simple: Get the values from the key and data into javascript variables after executing the Lua code.

Is that possible?

I'm reading the code from lua.vm.js but I cant find that guides me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-posted from https://github.com/kripken/lua.vm.js/issues/18

Use my branch/fork; repl can be found at https://daurnimator.github.io/lua.vm.js/repl.html

When a Lua variable is exposed to javascript; it is exposed as a function object; with methods invoke/get/set/etc. See https://github.com/daurnimator/lua.vm.js/blob/master/lua.js#L523

Using your example; expose the object to javascript somehow. e.g. in lua:

```
window.mydata = data
window.mykey = key
```

Then in javascript:

```
v1 = window.mydata.get(window.mykey)
v2 = window.mydata.get("a").get("b")
console.log(v1)
console.log(v2)
```

Comment: That did it! I had to use your branch because it doesn't work in the original

Comment: Could you please add example of invoke?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="./lua.vm.js"></script>

<script type="text/lua">
  print(js.global:myShow("test"))
</script>

<script>
myShow = function show(value)
{
    return value + " me"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Kindly provide an explanation of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer