# Iterating over Lua table in javascript with lua.vm.js

Tags: javascript, lua

A while ago I posted a [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885912/reading-lua-variables-from-javascript-using-lua-vm-js) question, regarding interaction between lua.vm.js and javascript.

Now I have a slightly different problem:

Lets assume that I have the following code in the [REPL](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua.vm.js/repl.html)

```
model = {}
model['test1'] = 1
model['test3'] = 2
model['test4'] = 3
model['test5'] = 4
model['test6'] = 5
local window = js.global
window.model = model
```

Because I'm using lua.vm.js, I now that from javascript I can get all the values by doing

```
window.model.get('test1')
window.model.get('test2')
window.model.get('test3')
```

But the problem with that is that I have to know beforehand that the entries at the table are "test1", "test2", etc.

Is there a way in javascript(or maybe by adding some more Lua code) that I can iterate all over the table without knowing all the entries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does native javascript `(for var in obj)` looping work?

Comment: @EtanReisner: no, Lua tables are not directly represented as JavaScript objects.

Comment: In Lua you can use `pairs` to iterate over all of the table entries. I can't find anything for lua.vm.js though; there's very little documentation for it.

Comment: Have you looked at [**moonshine**](https://github.com/gamesys/moonshine)? I bring it up only because lua.vm.js doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore whereas the developer behind moonshine is still very active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get the list of keys in `model` would be to use Lua directly.

From what I can see the `lua.vm.js` table object does not support iteration, but you can do that from JavaScript:

```
my_keys = L.execute('local r = {}; for k in pairs(model) do r[#r+1] = k end; return unpack(r)')
```

Then you can loop like this:

```
for (var i in my_keys) {
    console.log(my_keys[i], window.model.get(my_keys[i]));
}
```